# Python selenium clicking a button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, linktext

I am trying to write a python script to automatically download csv using the "Download CSV" button from the below link:
https://chartink.com/screener/copy-supertrend-negative-breakout-1103

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

DRIVER_PATH = r"C:\Users\u123456\Downloads\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe"
d = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
d.get('https://chartink.com/screener/copy-supertrend-negative-breakout-1103')
download_button = pd.read_html(d.find_element_by_class_name('btn btn-default buttons-excel buttons-html5 btn-primary'))[0]
#table = pd.read_html(d.find_element_by_id('DataTables_Table_0').get_attribute('outerHTML'))[0]
print(download_button)
```

I am not finding any clue on how to click that button and download it to local drive. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Edit: I tried the below code and got it working, Now I would like to know if we can find the filename and load it into pandas dataframe.

```
element = d.find_element_by_link_text("Download csv")
element.click()
```

Thanks,
mc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the element <kbd>Download csv</kbd> you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `link_text`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_link_text("Download csv").click()
  ```
- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.btn.btn-default.buttons-excel.buttons-html5.btn-primary[value='Download backtest']").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@value='Download backtest' and text()='Download csv']").click()
  ```

---

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Download csv"))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.btn.btn-default.buttons-excel.buttons-html5.btn-primary[value='Download backtest']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@value='Download backtest' and text()='Download csv']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks Debanjan. Can you also please let me know how to read this file dynamically into a dataframe?

Comment: Hi @Debanjan, I have found the solution to my original problem myself but thanks for your response too but I am looking for a solution on next step.

Comment: @mrcool4 As per your question heading _....Python selenium clicking a button.._ I thought your question was to click on the button. Hence was the answer. Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement. StackOverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.

Comment: accepted your answer, can you also please upvote the question as someone has deliberately negged the entire thread?